# Same object file in different static libraries when linking

Tags: c++, clang, static-linking

```
clang++ ... foo.cpp ... -o dir1/foo.o
clang++ ... foo.cpp ... -o dir2/foo.o
//The only difference beween the above two clang++ command lines
//is the output directory
llvm-ar ... dir1/lib1.a ...  dir1/foo.o ...
llvm-ar ... dir2/lib2.a ...  dir2/foo.o ...
clang++ ... dir1/lib1.a dir2/lib2.a ... -o lib.so
```

What happens to the duplicated symbols from foo.cpp when generating lib.so? Is any flag reqired to not to generate symbol duplication errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking multiple static libraries, when the same object file occurs in more than one of the provided libraries, will *not* result in any duplicate symbol errors (by default).

This is because the linker does not "combine the static libraries" into a final executable. It only combines the provided *object files* into the executable. The linker processes the list of object files and archive libraries left-to-right. When a static library is encountered, the linker checks to see if any of the library provided object files define a currently undefined symbol. Then, and only then, will pull in that object file.

In your example:

```
clang++ ... dir1/lib1.a dir2/lib2.a ... -o lib.so
```

consider two additional object files:

```
clang++ obj1.o dir1/lib1.a dir2/lib2.a obj2.o -o lib.so
```

If `obj1.o` references a symbol that exists in `foo.cpp`:

1. The linker will process and add `obj1.o` to the `lib.so`, noting that said symbol is undefined.
2. The linker will open `dir1/lib1.a` and check if any object files contained in the archive define said symbol. Because `foo.o` defines the symbol, `foo.o` will be added to `lib.so` and the symbol will be marked defined.
3. The linker will open `dir2/lib2.a`. But there are no currently undefined symbols so the duplicate object file will be ignored.
4. The linker will process and add `obj2.o` to the `lib.so`. The linker does **not** go back and re-processes `lib1.a` or `lib2.a`

Therefore no duplicate symbol error should be raised (by default, on Linux). To change this behaviour, you can use the linker option `--whole-archive`

```
clang++ ... -Wl,--whole-archive dir1/lib1.a dir2/lib2.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive ... -o lib.so
```

With `--whole-archive` all object files from the specified archive libraries will be added to the output. The above command then results in a "multiple definition" error for any symbols in `foo.cpp`.

This answer describes the behaviour on Linux, I believe AIX is different and will always add all encountered object files (from static libraries) to the output.

Comment: Then if "clang++ obj1.o dir1/lib1.a obj2.o dir2/lib2.a -o lib.so" and both obj1 and obj2 references foo.o , then there will be duplicated symbol error for global symbols in foo.o right? or will the linker just use symbols in the previous added foo.o and never look into the second foo.o?

Comment: Use to think the linker just pick the method from .a then put it into the result. If the linker add the whole .o in the .a into the result, static libraries is better to be desgined with as little code as possbile in each source file.

Comment: If "both obj1 and obj2 references foo.o", there will still be no duplicated symbols. When obj2 is processed, another look up is not needed because all the referenced symbols are considered resolved. (The linker is building a table of known symbols as it goes).

Comment: "If the linker add the whole .o in the .a into the result, static libraries is better to be desgined with as little code as possbile" - Technically, the linker pulls in sections not whole object files. By default the .text section contains all the functions together, but you can split them up to avoid the wasted space using "-ffunction-sections" when compiling the libraries